# Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'json'. while renaming xml attibute with xslt

Tags: json, xml, xslt

> Updated with Minimal, Complete and Verifiable information thanks [@Kenneth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/290085/kjhughes) for drawing my attention.

So, I'm trying to rename an xml attribute using xslt, but I keep getting this error message:

> Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'json'.

1. This is my source xml:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <data>
     <code>SO000009</code>
     <businessPartner>70833A356B9A428CBDDCD2A76A49681F</businessPartner>
     <startDateTime>2018-01-25T15:24:27Z</startDateTime>
     <subject>Test</subject>
     <equipments jsonArray="true">80202</equipments>
   </data>
   ```
2. This is how I want the xml to be:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
   <data xmlns:json="http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json">
     <code>SO000009</code>
     <businessPartner>70833A356B9A428CBDDCD2A76A49681F</businessPartner>
     <startDateTime>2018-01-25T15:24:27Z</startDateTime>
     <subject>Test</subject>
     <equipments json:Array="true">80202</equipments>
   </data>
   ```
3. And this is my xslt:

   ```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:template match="/data">
       <data xmlns:json="http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
       </data>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="@*">
       <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
         <xsl:value-of select="." />
       </xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="node()">
       <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
       </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="@jsonArray">
       <xsl:attribute name="json:Array">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
       </xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```

When I'm trying to convert my xml, I keep getting this message:

> Error occurred while compiling stylesheet 'CS_jsonArray.xslt'.
>
> Code:   0x80004005
>
> Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'json'.

Comment: **Never post code and XML as images**.  Use text formatted as code.  Click the [edit] link and correct.  Be sure to include a [mcve].

Comment: *When I'm trying to convert my xml*...and where is this trial?

Comment: The solution is to declare the undeclared namespace prefix: 'json'. You did not show us your stylesheet, but you can find many examples if you search for them.

Answer (score 0):

After looking in the 'Related' sidebar, I did found the answer to my own question.

> [XSL transformation - Namespace prefix undeclared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700926/xsl-transformation-namespace-prefix-undeclared?rq=1)

So for those who have a same issue, be sure the namespace you want to change the attribute names for, is also in the xslt tag itself...

This is how my xslt started:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>...
```

This is how I changed it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:json="http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>...
```